# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources related to the English language
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5491).

Comment: Would a memorization tool be on-topic here? I was thinking of adding Anki, a tool that helps me remember rare words like obstreperous, cynosure, atavistic, etc.

Comment: Try posting an ad and seeing what the community thinks of it. That's probably the better way to see what people feel.

Comment: Do the new community ads go up in January? I forget.

Comment: @KitZFox There's going to be an announcement about that actually.

Answer (score 18):

[image: No general reference, please!]

Comment: I like the idea of this advert, but I'm not keen on the fact that it promotes one particular dictionary and that dictionary isn't included in the actual image part of the ad.

Comment: @starsplusplus I specifically chose onelook.com because it's not a dictionary itself but a dictionary search engine: "19,633,003 words in 1061 dictionaries indexed". For example: search for [idea](http://www.onelook.com/?w=idea&ls=a).

Comment: But to me there's still a difference between what the ad is saying and what it's actually linking to. If you want to advertise onelook (which is not a bad idea - a dictionary search engine is handy, and very relevant to ELU users), why not *actually* advertise onelook - say that it's a dictionary search engine, what it's called, and something promotional about it? At least include the name and logo. At the moment this reads like a meta site guideline but goes on to link to a specific tool.

Comment: @starsplusplus and that's precisely why it's so good. It works both to advertise a useful resource and to educate new users on how the site works and what we expect from them. As far as I'm concerned, I'd have upvoted this even if it had no target and was just a banner suggesting that people look up words in dictionaries instead of asking here.

Comment: If a links out is the right thing to do, onelook is probably the right place, but I clicked on this ad thinking (based on the branding) it might link to somewhere on meta or some other ELU page and was surprised to be taken off Stack Exchange completely.

Comment: It would be better to link wiktionary.org, which is both freely licensed and non-profit and can provide definitions of English words in 170 languages.

Comment: @Nemo Onelook indexes Wiktionary's coverage along with lots of others, so you're more likely to get a good result that way. Wiktionary still has quite a few gaps.

Comment: @Hugo few parse Wiktionary correctly, hence it's usually better to link it directly. Are there details on how they crawl it? Wiktionary currently has 25 millions of entries.

Comment: Excellent...should be bigger and should be included in the "Ask a Question" page right next to the text entry box

Answer (score 16):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 16):

[image: Come visit English Language Learners!]

Comment: This is the result of a discussion about migrating questions to ELL - perhaps we can head these questions off even earlier than that.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Write for the EL&U Community Blog!]

Answer (score 12):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/english.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Comment: This is an adaption of [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12383).

Comment: "The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels"

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Not a problem here; see [Community Promotion Ads - 2014](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884) and [Community Promotion Ads - 2012](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/998).

Comment: What if there are 100+ bounties?

Comment: @Glorfindel  Was it really *necessary* to bump an out-of-date/obsolete question, one that has been replaced by the [2019 version](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11991/community-promotion-ads-2019)? Yes, the image has returned but  how important was it?   This post will stick around for weeks giving visitors the unfortunate impression that nothing happens here for weeks on end...Oh wait, that's actually true

Comment: It's an [automated process](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f), and its bumping is rate-limited (and anyway, on EL&U Meta it's finished). It's a somewhat useful edit if somebody wants to copy it for the next Community Ads post ...

Answer (score 12):

[image: Writing exercise chat]

Answer (score -1):

[image: Would you like to learn Korean? Join Korean Language and Usage]

Answer (score -5):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: Any website with its own means of commenting has little use for social networking relationships.

Answer (score -10):

[image: ELU: because you say 'tomato' ...]

Comment: Love the idea, but I think it's better suited for ELL...

Comment: How about change it to link to ELL?

Comment: @oerkelens I think pointing it to ELL would be a bit tongue in cheek. I really meant it to show that all English dialects can be discussed here, and they are all equally valid in their own right. There is no such thing as a native English speaker, every who speaks English natively does so in a dialect, and phrases that define a dialect are neither 'wrong' nor 'pidgin' and that all dialects should be treated equally at EL&U.

Comment: @Hugo - see comment above

Comment: @Frank In which dialect of English do native speakers routinely call questions 'doubts'? It's a very common mixup for ESL speakers, but not one I've ever heard native speakers make.

Comment: @curiousdanni I'm not entirely sure; this Q&A suggests Southern India http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question. It may be a 'mistake' in some dialects but the prevalence of it's use suggests to me that it is, or is becoming, standard in some. Dictionaries record usage, they don't define it. I'm sure it won't be long until some of the major dictionaries show _doubt, n. 6. question (most frequent in Indian English)_ and then using _doubt_ to mean _question_ will be pukka.

Comment: Oerkelens said "I think it's better suited for ELL". You responded: "I really meant it to show that all English dialects can be discussed here, and they are all equally valid in their own right". Nevertheless, I think Oerkelens has a reasonable point: the tone of "Helping people with English [...]" is perfectly consistent with ELL, but at variance with EL&U's self-description as "a question and answer site for **linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts".**

Comment: @ErikKowal _Helping people with English_ not _Helping people learn English_.

Comment: @Frank - Reread my comment: I never said "Helping people *learn* English". That is *your* invention.

Comment: @ErikKowal ELL is for helping people learning English, ELU is for helping people who already know English.

Comment: @Frank - OK, I now understand what you were getting at three comments ago. My point is that the **tone** of your ad seems better geared to the **ELL site.** The very use of the word 'helping' creates the misleading impression that the EL&U site is intended for beginning or basic learners to ask basic questions. That's not what a Q&A site "for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts" is about.

Comment: @ErikKowal I'm not sure _abetting, assisting, supporting_ are any better, but I doubt any change to _Helping_ will make it a popular community advert.

Comment: What do you think of "The site for all varieties of English"?

Comment: @ErikKowal Maybe - with a change to _all dialects of English_?

Comment: That sounds good to me too.

Comment: @ErikKowal Changed - but I still don't think it'll be very welcomed.

Comment: Well, we'll see. I've upvoted it.

Comment: What kind of dialect is "we can do the needful" from? And it's still not been demonstrated that "doubt" used in this way is from a variety used by first language speakers of English.

Comment: @curiousdannii _do the needful_ is British English (also AmE and CanE). A search in Google Books will turn up thousands of uses. OED records _doing the needful_ from 1710 _4. a. the needful, what is necessary or requisite. Esp. in phr. to do the needful._

Comment: @Frank Huh. Is it just archaic or still current anywhere? [Google Ngrams says archaic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+needful&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20needful%3B%2Cc0). Still, archaic dialects are allowed, so that's okay.

Comment: @curiousdannii White China: Finding the Divine in the Everyday by Molly Wolf published 2005, not archaic. She is Canadian.

Comment: -1 You seem to be "making fun" of the way Indians speak.

Comment: "In which dialect of English do native speakers routinely call questions 'doubts'?"  This question doesn't make any sense.  The relevant dialects are almost entirely spoken by non-native speakers.  That doesn't mean they're not real dialects.