# Has EL&U more moderators than those in the list?

Tags: support

An answer to the  question ( [One word- someone so scare that he can't move](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231531/one-word-someone-so-scared-that-he-cant-move/231568#231568)) has been deleted by Mr. Robert Cartaino. Looking at his profile he appears to be a moderator to a numbers of different sites ( EL&U included), but he is not in the [list](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) of this site. 
Are there other moderators that are not in the EL&U list? 
This probably refers to some regulation I am not aware of ( sorry for that).  Can anyone explain pls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) have moderator privileges on every site, including mSE (the only site where there are no elected moderators).

They pop in from time to time. For example, [Grace Note](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8566) handles the [Community Promotion Ads](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5491/community-promotion-ads-2015). Occasionally they may take “normal” moderator actions too, as here, particularly if moderation needs to happen quickly and members of the site team aren’t online. In that regard, yes, there are more moderators here than just those [elected on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) specifically.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would have deleted that answer too. It's OK for near-identical answers to be almost simultaneous (within a minute or two), but [Not Alright At All](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/if-the-answer-i-was-going-to-submit-has-already-been-submitted-what-should-i-do) for an answer to attempt to cash in **a day later**.